# Регулярные выражения в PHP верхний регистр

Tags: php

Нужно вернуть только ту строку, в которой все буквы в верхнем регистре. Хочу сделать это через регулярные выражение. Есть вот такое выражение:

```
/'?![A-Z]'/
```

Но оно почему то плоха работает с числами и символами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так

```
/^[A-Z]+$/
```

чтобы от начала и до конца строки были только заглавные буквы.

Comment: А можете мне подсказать как написат регулярку, котоаря будет брать по одной букве из строки

Comment: Если надо перебрать посимвольно строку, то можно обращаться к строке как к массиву ` $str[3]` - от нуля до длины строки -1.

Answer (score 0):

лучше так, иначе может быть путаница

^[^a-z]*$